# Ошибка C3861 Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Постоянно при компиляции программы

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
cout << "Hello";
return 0;
}
```

Выдаёт ошибку C3861

Comment: У меня без проблем компилируются. Где у Вас выдается ошибка (на какой строке)?

Comment: Открывается вообще другой файл , а в моём даже не подсвечивается. НАШЁЛ РЕШЕНИЕ : установка sdk для Windows XP

Comment: В случае ошибки лучше не только код, но и текст ошибки сразу сообщать...